# Nmap Scan Shows Filtered Ports for VNC, RDP, SAMBA & SSH on iOS - is this normal?

Tags: network, nmap, ios

I ran an nmap scan on my iPad’s IP address and the results showed the following ports listed below available in a filtered state.  See screenshot for the actual terminal results.

[image: nmap results]

- SSH
- Netbios-ssn
- ms-wbt-server (Remote Desktop)
- 4 different VNC ports
- And an iPhone Sync port

This can’t be normal, right?  There are no apps installed that would explain these ports and the device is not jailbroken.

Comment: You might want to add the exact nmap command to your post. Different parameters could yield different results.

Answer (score 2):

> This can’t be normal, right?

Wrong, it can be normal.

Your scan shows that there is only one open port, on port 62078.

The results will be similar for other iDevices. For example, an iPhone 11 Pro on my network shows 985 closed ports, 14 filtered ports, and one open port (port 62078).

Comment: Ok, good to know.  Are your filtered ports similar to the one’s listed above - rdp, ssh, vnc, etc

Comment: No, they are different. BTW, filtered is (in a sense) "better" than closed--the packets are just getting dropped. The names that nmap is using for the "filtered" ports are just based on typical/common services associated with the port historically, there's no indication that any services are actually running--the packets are just totally dropped so nmap has no idea what's up with those ports.

Comment: Here the the definitions of open, closed, filtered: https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html